# Creating directories with sequential numbering

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, directory

I am trying to create a sequence of identical directories with names like 'file001' in sequence from 1 to 512. I am running the following in the shell:

```
for i in $(seq 001 512):
    do
        mkdir file$i
    done
```

Though this is creating all 512 directories, but they are being labelled as 'file1','file2'... instead of 'file001','file002' and so on. 
Can anyone please suggest some other way to create the folders in the way I require?

Comment: Does your `seq` have a `-w` option?

Answer (score 6):

Try this instead:

```
mkdir file{001..512}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use either of

```
for num in $(seq -w 001 512); do
    mkdir "file$num"
done
```

or, with `bash` release 4.0 or later (i.e not the default `bash` on macOS),

```
mkdir file{001..512}
```

With older `bash` if `seq` is unavailable:

```
for num in {1..512}; do
    mkdir "file$( printf '%03d' "$num" )"
done
```

Comment: Note that `{001..512}` comes from `zsh` decades before bash. macOS has always had `zsh`, `zsh` even used to be `/bin/sh` there. You can also do `printf '%03d\n' {1..512} | xargs mkdir`

Answer (score 0):

No need of for Loop. Try this :

```
mkdir `echo file{001..512}`
```

As pointed by in comments :

> There is no need for command substitution and echo.

So, **[Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)** is sufficient enough to achieve the task :

```
mkdir file{001..512}
```

Comment: There is no need for command substitution and `echo`.

Comment: Yes, just saw your answer. :)